# changing branch to head using tortoise svn

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have a weird requirement where I need to change the current trunk into a branch and one of branches into trunk. I was trying to figure out how this can be done with tortoise svn client. I don't want to merge, but I just need to exchange the head and a branch.Any clues on this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically a good old swap, so you need a temporary name and three operations:

```
svn rename http://example.com/svn/trunk http://example.com/svn/tmp
svn rename http://example.com/svn/branch http://example.com/svn/trunk
svn rename http://example.com/svn/tmp http://example.com/svn/branch
```

Same with TortoiseSVN, just use the repository browser.